# What is the title to this song on Fairy Tail?

Tags: fairy-tail, music

What is the song that starts playing at 21:05 of Fairy Tail episode 124?

Comment: Needed or not, linking to obvious illegal media sources is not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the song is called Kizuna.
[Kizuna-Fairy Tail OST](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RqxmFkmEoZQ)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.